# Limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n!}{n^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

How can I compute this limit:
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n!}{n^n}$. 
I have tried taking the n-th root but then I have problem managing the factorial.
Thanks to everyone who will help!

Comment: $$
\frac{n!}{n^n} = \frac{1 \times 2 \times 3 \times 4 \dots \times n}{n \times n \times n \times n \dots \times n}
$$
How does it look like to you?

Comment: @user502940 Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

By ratio test

$$\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\frac{n^n}{n!} =\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n}$$

and recall that $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\to e$.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to involve a root or ratio test here.
$$
\frac{n!}{n^n} = \frac{1 \times 2 \times \cdots \times n}{n \times n \times \cdots \times n} = \frac1n \times \frac2n \times \cdots \times \frac nn < \frac 1n.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_n=\frac{n!}{n^n}$

Prove that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \to \frac{1}{e}<1$

Thus from ratio test for sequences we have that $a_n \to 0$